# Working Set of files - Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hi does anyone know of a plugin for visual studio 2012 that will let me add files to a current working set. 
I have a large solution worked on by many people and navigating around it takes me a lot of dev time.

Up to now i've been using bookmarks, but something smarter would be good, the bookmarks seem a bit simple.

Eg. being able to book mark a whole folder would be useful!

thanks

Matt